# Reading Product Images Data

Tags: magento-1.7, product, php, image, html

I am currently displaying the product images for product editing. In this I have to get the produt images and insert into the 'src' of an  html element.

I know how to get the product image ..But how can i get its data and this data can be set as src of an img html element?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you try any code for this?

Comment: yes  @KeyulShah  .I tried this.'if(count($product->getMediaGalleryImages())>0){
            foreach($product->getMediaGalleryImages as $image){
               Mage::log($image->getUrl());
            }
        }'.But It count is 0 even this product has one image.

Comment: As per Standard if you want to fetch the product Image then you can try

$product_image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($productmodel,'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize(width,height).'';

Comment: make sure you have assign small_image at product level don't need to fetch data as per your logic

Comment: Thank you @KeyulShah .I am trying to get the image data as php Imagick readImage()..

Comment: I solved without using imagick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved My problem with following code:

```
<?php 
$image = "pro-image-1.jpg";
$image_data=base64_encode(file_get_contents(Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'image')));
$src = 'data:'.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$image_data;
?>
<img src='<?php echo $src; ?> '/>
```

[Source](http://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php).

Comment: This is for only one image.

Comment: sounds good :)......